# When removing all Windows partitions, do I run into problems when reinstalling Windows in future?

Tags: windows-10, license, system-reserved-partition

The Thinkpad T460 I got from my company came with Windows 10 preinstalled. However, my team is working in GNU/Linux exclusively. I would like to totaly remove all the Windows partitions so I can make use of this space. However, it might happen that I migrate to a team developing in Windows somewhen in future. I think removing Windows should be unproblematic, but...

### Question:

Can I run into unforeseen problems when I want to reinstall Windows in future? I'm far from being a Windows expert and don't want to find out that I shot myself in the foot afterwards.

### Things I considered:

- This machine has the Windows 10 license key embedded into UEFI. Hence, removing Windows should not somehow mean a loss of my Windows 10 license key. Correct? It does not have a license sticker or anything similar.
- The computer did not come with some kind of boot media, however, it seems to me that Windows 10 images are available at Microsoft's website for free. (Correct?) So I don't expect problems in this regard as well.
- I shall create a full backup before touching my partition table.

### Disclaimer

Naturally, one would simply ask the companys IT department, but there is no such thing in the company I work for. We are all software engineers and are expected to take care about such things ourselves.

### Screenshot of my partitions

[image: Screenshot of hard disk layout]

Comment: "This machine has the Windows 10 license key embedded into be UEFI." - This is false.  The license key is actually stored in the ACPI Table.  *UEFI and the ACPI are two seperate standards.*  In order to install Windows on the device you have, download the ISO, and install Windows.  Once installed Windows will automatically activated.  **That is the ONLY thing you have to do.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conclusions (although wording may be a bit off) is correct.

You can safely remove all partitions and it won't harm you in the future, if you don't mind removing linux partitions in order to make room for a windows partition.

That said, you can download [a tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) from microsoft, designed to create a USB install medium to install windows 10 from. In order to create an install medium, you need windows 10 first (the tool only runs on windows, and when you run it from your windows 10 install, it will detect which version you are using (home/pro/enterprise) and create an install medium that uses that version of windows. This is important to ensure your pc will activate in the future.).

You need a 3 or 6GB USB Stick depending on if you want to create only x86 or x64 or both as install medium. Although almost all the time you only want an x64 version, a system with less than 4GB RAM would benefit from an x86 version.

My recommendation would be to create that usb stick prior to deleting the windows partitions.